# Collision of two bodies, one in 2D motion and the other in 1D

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, collision

This question is basically based on derivation of relativistic mass. Derivation in my book seems to be a lot puzzling because of a certain part which is the notion of collision as mentioned in the title.

[image]

In the image S' frame is moving with a relative velocity of v with respect to S. Both the frames are noving parallel to each other as well as x-axis(suppose). If a ball B is thrown downwards from the S frame and another ball A of same mass is thrown upwards from S' frame with same velocity such that both of them collide, how will the S frame observe the trajectory of both the balls? If there were no collisions then it is certain that he will observe the trajectory of the ball A to be diagonally linear. But since there is an ELASTIC collision, initially he will observe the B ball is falling exactly parallel to his y-axis. And after collision what will he observe? According to his perspective the ball A is in 2D motion but the ball B is in 1D motion. So after collision he should observe that both of them are in 2D motion(depending on the velocity and the conditions), otherwise if their final motion is along the same dimension through which they have been before collision then the momentum will not be conserved.

So thing which seems puzzling to me is that my book states that the observer S will observe the trajectory of ball A to be like a "V" shape due to collision but the trajectory of ball B is a straight line parallel to his y axis. This seems incorrect to me intuitively.

So I am looking for a bit guidance regarding whether I am wrong or the statements of my book are wrong.

Comment: Is there an effect of gravity? If 'no', your book is right.

Comment: No, there is no influency of gravity in this case. But how is that correct? Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: You said earlier that the trajectory of A is paraboloic.  Now you have corrected it as 'diagonally linear'.  So I think you have solved your problem. Feel free to ask for any clarification.

Comment: To be honwst I did get that part of the issue of parabolic trajectory which was misunderstood earlier. But I am still confused why the ball B is linear(1D) w.r.t the observer and the ball A moves along a V shaped trajectory. Shouldn't both of them be in 2D motion after collision? Because the horizontal component of the momentum of ball A needs to be conserved, right?

Comment: I misspoke slightly in above comment. Your argument is partially correct. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider this relative to the S frame. You seem to have a good understanding of the motion before the collision. You are confused here as to why both balls do not make 2D motion. It is reasonable to think so as well as you are correct. Think of it this way. The vertical momentum of the system before the collision is zero. There is only a horizontal momentum. Let us assume that the horizontal velocities of both balls after the collision are $v_1$ and $v_2$, respectively. Then $$v = v_1 + v_2$$ Inevitably the vertical velocities of the balls must be the same. Let's take it as $u$ before the collision and $u_0$ after the collision. The initial energy and the final energy of the system should not change because this is an elastic collision.  That is, $$2u^2 + v^2 = 2u_0^2 + v_1^2 + v_2^2$$
$$2u^2 + v^2 = 2u_0^2 + v^2-2v_1v_2$$
$$2u^2 = 2u_0 ^2-2v_1v_2$$
There are a number of $u, u_0, v_1, v_2$ ​​values ​​that can be used for this.

Let's consider this figuratively. Below I have mentioned two such instances.

[image]
The red and blue lines here indicate the direction of motion and the white arrows represent the impulse forces during the collision. According to these pictures, it is obvious that the balls will take different paths at different cases.

The speeds vary depending on how they collide. Therefore the directions of travel are different. Here your book has considered one such incident.

But, it seems to me that you are in a slightly wrong opinion.

> So after collision he should observe that both of them are in 2D motion(depending on the velocity and the conditions), otherwise if their final motion is along the same dimension through which they have been before collision then the momentum will not be conserved.

Why do you think momentum is not conserved? It is wrong. This can be happened (it is not mandatory). A goes back down with same velocity it went up and B goes up with same velocity it came down. So both initial and final vertical momenta are equal to zero and there is nothing wrong with that. Also, the V-shape here indicates that the initial horizontal velocity of A remains the same after the collision. Since B has no horizontal velocity, the horizontal momentum at the beginning and at the end is considered to be A's. Therefore, this cannot be said to be impossible, because momentum is obviously conserved. In case of collision as in the second image above, the directions of travel are set like this.

Comment: I am basically confused about the horizontal component of the motion. Same thing for a ball hitting a wall and then reflects. Why isn't this horizontal component of one making the other one to deviate slightly?

Comment: At the beginning the horizontal velocity component of the system was to the right side as well as at the end. So it is clear that the momentum is conserved. A ball hitting a wall is a slightly different incident from this question. You can ask it as another question. Momentum conservation is valid there too.  I think questions about that have been asked on PSE.  It's good to find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ACB